# How do I stack WordPress posts into 3 separate columns using PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to figure out how to stack posts into three separate columns by using PHP, I've done a lot of research on this question, but I can't see to find much information on how to do this.

I know how to get the layout I want using HTML, but how do I get PHP to output the content into my columns?

Here is a picture of the design I'm trying to achieve: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYQMI.jpg

This is a standard blog page using the posts, no custom post types involved.

My current PHP code:

```
<div class="container blog-page-container">
 <?php if (have_posts()) {
    $count = 0;
    echo '<div class="row">';
    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        if($count == 3) {
            $count = 0;
            echo '</div><div class="row blog-additional-row">';
        };
        ?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="testimonial-background">
                <div class="testimonial-text">
            <span>
                <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                <p><?php echo the_content(); ?></p>
                <p><strong><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></strong></p>
            </span>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php $count++;
    endwhile;
    echo '</div>';
}; ?>
</div>
```

But this is how I want the code to be output: https://jsfiddle.net/wrpuu7wh/

```js
$('.testimonial-text:odd').addClass("testimonial-text-opposite");
```

```css
.col-md-12 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.col-md-4 {
  width: 33.33333333%;
  float: left;
}

.testimonial-background {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.testimonial-text {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #4E0B1C;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-right: 40px;
}

.testimonial-text-opposite {
  color: #4E0B1C;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #4E0B1C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/js/all.js"></script>

<div class="container blog-page-container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. </p>
                    <p><strong>Post 1</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 4</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 7</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 2</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 5</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor..</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 8</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 3</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 6</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="testimonial-background">
        <div class="testimonial-text">
          <span>
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-3x"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscingelit. Nam velit dolor,     tincidunt cursus nisl eget, auctor vehicula sem. Aliquam eget nunclacinia, pulvinar erat eget, finibus mauris.</p>
                    <p><strong>Post 9</strong></p>
                </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is a standard blog page and is not using any custom post types.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**SOLUTION:**

```
<?php
/* Total published posts should be returned this way: */
$count_posts = wp_count_posts()->publish;
$count_rows = round($count_posts/3);
$post_columns = array(
array(),
array(),
array()
);
?>
<div class="container blog-page-container">
    <?php if (have_posts()) {
        $count = 0;
        while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            $post_column_number = $count;
            $post_columns[$count%3][] = array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'content' => get_the_content()
            );
            $count++;
        endwhile;
        foreach( $post_columns as $pc ) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
            foreach( $pc as $pt ) {
                echo "
                <div class='col-md-12'>
                    <div class='testimonial-background'>
                        <div class='testimonial-text'>
                            <span>
                                <i class='fas fa-quote-left fa-3x'></i>
                                <p>{$pt['content']}</p>
                                <p><strong>{$pt['title']}</strong> </p>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
            };
            echo '</div>';
        };
    };?>
```

Comment: what you trying to achieve?  can you share screenshot for expected output?

Comment: Hi, my JSFiddle should be clear, but if it's not working here's a picture of the design I'm trying to achieve: https://imgur.com/a/RtALRzN

Comment: check this plugin http://callmecavs.com/bricks.js/

Comment: I would like to avoid using an external library if possible, there must be a way to tell the PHP to output the posts without needing to us JS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
$count = 1;
<?php if (have_posts()) {
echo '<div class="row">';
while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if($count == 3) {
        $count = 0;
        echo '</div>';
    }else if ($count == 1){
      echo '<div class="col-md-4">';
    }
    ?>
//enter code here
<?php $count++;
endwhile;
echo '</div>';
 }; ?>
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: Hi, although this will place 3 posts in a row, then start a new row. I want the posts to show up in a col-md-4. 
Check my JSFiddle for a better example: https://jsfiddle.net/wrpuu7wh/

Comment: I updated the code, please check this will add col-md-4 at first post and finish it after 3 post every time.

Comment: I've updated my post, I hope it's clearer to understand, if not, here is a screenshot of how it should look: https://imgur.com/a/RtALRzN, this is a bit more complicated than just having 3 posts per row.

Answer (score 0):

I used this library for doing 3 coloumns https://masonry.desandro.com/

1. Register in your `functions.php` the library

   ```
   function masonry_js() {
      wp_register_script(
          'mansonry_script', 
          get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/masonry.pkgd.min.js', 
          array('jquery'),
          '1.1',
          true
      );
     wp_enqueue_script('masonry_script');
     wp_register_script(
         'mansory_custom_script', 
         get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/js/masonry.js', 
         array('jquery'),
         '1.1',
         true
     );
     wp_enqueue_script('mansory_custom_script');
   }
   add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'masonry_js', 999 );
   ```
2. Add library file on child theme directory
3. Write your own code in jquery for calling the masonry library and add it to the file `masonry.js` in the folder `js` in your child theme.

   ```
   $('.grid').masonry({
      // options...
      itemSelector: '.grid-item',
      columnWidth: 200
   });
   ```
4. Write the wordPress loop with the right classes:

   ```
    <div class="masonry">
       <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
       <div class="gutter-sizer"></div>
       <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
           <div class="id" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> >
               <div class="grid-item">
                   <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                       the_post_thumbnail();
                   } else { ?> <img src=""> <?php } ?>
                   <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>

                   <p class="content"><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 30, '...'); ?> </p>
                   <h3 class="button"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> See More </a></h3>

               </div><!--/.masonry-entry-->
           </div>

       <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div>
   ```
5. Write css for grid-item